# javascript successive conditions in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I have a javascript function. The 3rd condition is not working, it works when it's alone in the loop but not with the other conditions, I don't know why. Anybody can help??

```
function verif(ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5, ref6) {
    document.forms["form"].intitule.value = ref1;
    document.forms["form"].montant.value = ref2;
    document.getElementById(ref3).selected = true;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 400; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("newDay").options[i].text == ref4) {
            document.getElementById("newDay").options[i].selected = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("newMonth").options[i].text == ref5) {
            document.getElementById("newMonth").options[i].selected = true;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("newYear").options[i].text == ref6) {
            document.getElementById("newYear").options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably there's more `option` elements in `#newYear` than other `select`s. When `i` grows larger than the length of the shortest `select` element, an error is triggered and execution is stopped.

Comment: Do you get an error in your console? (e.g. `cannot get property text of undefined` or something?) Is `ref6` set? Does _#newYear_ have more than `400` options?

Answer (score 0):

Add each of the condition in its own try catch and see if any of the condition is throwing error. I have added alert to help you debug.

```
function verif(ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5, ref6) {
    document.forms["form"].intitule.value = ref1;
    document.forms["form"].montant.value = ref2;
    document.getElementById(ref3).selected = true;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 400; i++) {
        try{
        if (document.getElementById("newDay").options[i].text == ref4) {
            document.getElementById("newDay").options[i].selected = true;
        }
        }catch(err){
          alert(err);
        }
        try{
        if (document.getElementById("newMonth").options[i].text == ref5) {
            document.getElementById("newMonth").options[i].selected = true;
        }
        }catch(err){
          alert(err);
        }
        try
        {
        if (document.getElementById("newYear").options[i].text == ref6) {
            document.getElementById("newYear").options[i].selected = true;
        }
        }catch(err){
          alert(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: This code might produce up to `400 * 3 = 1200` alert dialogs.

Comment: That depends if exception is thrown or not. Alert is just added to find the exception. Could be replaced console.log method also

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do one loop for all `3` items. The advantage of that is the lower number of required iterations, but you've included no code to ensure that you won't try to look up *undefined* `<option>`s. Next, consider how the advantage of using one loop is really to save on the number of *iterations*, and therefore having two loops, the second picking up where the first ended, will still have the minimal iteration count.

Therefore, if you want to save on loop **iterations**, you could try something like this, where the items in the loops decrease depending on how far along `i` is and what has been found already. This does result in some code duplication, though. Note how the loops are sorted in order of *months* then *days* then *years*, because *12 < 31 < x* (I'm assuming *x* is about `400`), therefore ensuring that you won't try to look up, e.g. the *20th month*, which of course would not exist.

```
function verif(ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5, ref6) {
    document.forms["form"].intitule.value = ref1;
    document.forms["form"].montant.value = ref2;
    document.getElementById(ref3).selected = true;

    var i = 0, found = {day: 0, month: 0, year: 0},
        elm = {
            days: document.getElementById("newDay"),
            months: document.getElementById("newMonth"),
            years: document.getElementById("newYear")
        };
    // months length = min(days, months, years)
    while (++i < elm.months.length && !found.months) {
        if (elm.days.options[i].text == ref4) {
            found.days = elm.days.options[i].selected = true;
        }
        if (elm.months.options[i].text == ref5) {
            found.months = elm.months.options[i].selected = true;
        }
        if (elm.years.options[i].text == ref6) {
            found.years = elm.years.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
    // days length = min(days, years)
    while (++i < elm.days.length && !found.days) {
        if (elm.days.options[i].text == ref4) {
            found.days = elm.days.options[i].selected = true;
        }
        if (elm.years.options[i].text == ref6) {
            found.years = elm.years.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
    // only years left
    while (++i < elm.years.length && !found.years) {
        if (elm.years.options[i].text == ref6) {
            found.years = elm.years.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You might also notice I didn't include any `break` statements, this is because if we find something which will still be looked for in a later loop, we still want to search for the item specific to the current loop, we don't want to skip the other checks for that same iteration and we also don't want to waste time on that later loop. Hence, a piece of code which does a similar action to `break` is in the *`<condition>`* instead.